# Prove that operator of mirror plane $x+z=0$ is linear and find its' matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I am not familiar with term  *mirror plane* , hence I don't know how to solve this problem. As for operator itself, maybe if I select basis $(x,0,0), (0,y,0), (0,0,z)$ then I would express $x+z$ this way:

$ \mathcal{A}(x,0,0) = (1,0)$

$ \mathcal{A}(0,y,0) = (0,0)$

$ \mathcal{A}(0,0,z) = (0,1)$

Could you explain in detail how to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe it is asking for the matrix representing the orthogonal projection into the plane.

Comment: It is asking matrix of operator.

Comment: There may be a translation issue here, but it sounds like they're asking for the [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)) through the plane $x + z = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, I think the question is asking about the reflection through the plane given by $x + z = 0$.

That is, we take a vector, and reflect it through the plane perpendicular to the vector $(1,0,1)$.

Here is one way to solve the problem:

Note that the vectors
$$
v_1 = (1,0,1), v_2 = (1,0,-1), v_3 = (0,1,0)
$$
Form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  In particular, we note that the plane $x + z = 0$ is given by the span of $\{v_2,v_3\}$, and the direction perpendicular to the plane is given by $v_1$.

Letting $A$ refer to the operator representing this reflection, we have
$$
A(v_1) = -v_1\\
A(v_2) = v_2\\
A(v_3) = v_3
$$
So, letting $\mathcal B = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, we note that
$$
[A]_{\mathcal B \to \mathcal B} = 
\pmatrix{
-1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1
}
$$